# Measuring the sort times in Java

Tags: java, sorting, benchmarking

I wrote a program to test and verify the running time of "insertion sort" which should be O(n^2).  The output doesn't look right to me and it doesn't seem to vary much between different runs.  The other odd thing is that the second time through is always the smallest.  I expect there to be greater variance every time I run the program but the run times don't seem to fluctuate as much as I would expect.  I'm just wondering if there are some kind of optimizations or something being done by the JVM or compiler.  I have similar code in C# and it seems to vary more and the output is as expected.  I am not expecting the running times to square every time but I am expecting them to increase more than they are and I certainly expect a much greater variance at the last iteration.

Sample Output (it doesn't vary enough for me to include multiple outputs):

- 47
- 20 (this one is ALWAYS the lowest... it makes no sense!)
- 44
- 90
- 133
- 175
- 233
- 298
- 379
- 490

  ```
  public class SortBench {

  public static void main(String args[]){

      Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

      for(int k = 100; k <= 1000; k += 100)
      {
          //Keep track of time
          long time = 0;
          //Create new arrays each time
          int[] a = new int[k];
          int[] b = new int[k];
          int[] c = new int[k];
          int[] d = new int[k];
          int[] e = new int[k];

          //Insert random integers into the arrays
          for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
          {
              int range = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
              a[i] = rand.nextInt(range);
              b[i] = rand.nextInt(range);
              c[i] = rand.nextInt(range);
              d[i] = rand.nextInt(range);
              e[i] = rand.nextInt(range);
          }
          long start = System.nanoTime();
          insertionSort(a);
          long end = System.nanoTime();
          time += end-start;

          start = System.nanoTime();
          insertionSort(b);
          end = System.nanoTime();
          time += end-start;

          start = System.nanoTime();
          insertionSort(c);
          end = System.nanoTime();
          time += end-start;

          start = System.nanoTime();
          insertionSort(d);
          end = System.nanoTime();
          time += end-start;

          start = System.nanoTime();
          insertionSort(e);
          end = System.nanoTime();
          time += end-start;

          System.out.println((time/5)/1000);
      }
  }
      static void insertionSort(int[] a)
      {
          int key;
          int i;
          for(int j = 1; j < a.length; j++)
          {
              key = a[j];
              i = j - 1;
              while(i>=0 && a[i]>key)
              {
                  a[i + 1] = a[i];
                  i = i - 1;
              }
              a[i + 1] = key;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warm up the JVM's JIT optimization of your function, memory allocators, TLB, CPU frequency, and so on before the timed region.

Add some untimed calls right after seeding the RNG, before your existing timing loop.

```
Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()); 

// warmup
for(int k = 100; k <= 10000; k += 100) 
{
    int[]w = new int[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++) 
    { 
       int range = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
       w[i] = rand.nextInt(range); 
       insertionSort(w);
     }
 }
```

Results with warming:

```
4
16
27
47
68
97
126
167
201
250
```

Results without warming:

```
62
244
514
206
42
59
80
98
122
148
```

Comment: Did you mean int[] w = new int[k]

Comment: No - takes too long to warm (extra 7 or 8 seconds).  Just wanted JIT to do its thing around insertionSort().  But I think either will work to warm.

Comment: Ahh Ok.  The extra few seconds didn't bother me, I suppose it's not a big deal either way.  I also wanted to mention that I'm testing other algorithms so in the "warm up loop" I had to repopulate w with new random ints and then also call the other algorithms I wanted to bench like mergeSort(w, 0, w.length - 1).

Comment: Agree - One point others should glean is when doing performance testing, a warming period is usually needed.

Answer (score 4):

On your first iteration, you're *also* measuring the JIT time (or at least *some* JIT time - HotSpot will progressively optimize further). Run it several times first, and *then* start measuring. I suspect you're seeing the benefits of HotSpot as time goes on - the earlier tests are slowed down by both the time taken to JIT *and* the fact that it's not running as optimal code. (Compare this with .NET, where the JIT only runs *once* - there's no progressive optimization.)

If you *can*, allocate all the memory first too - and make sure nothing is garbage collected until the end. Otherwise you're including allocation and GC in your timing.

You should also consider trying to take more samples, with `n` going up another order of magnitude, to get a better idea of how the time increases. (I haven't looked at what you've done carefully enough to work out whether it really *should* be O(n<sup>2</sup>).)